# how to delete blob in windows azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I saved some files in the blob, my blob file structure are :

```
/container/B1/1
/container/B1/2
/container/B1/3
/container/B1/4

/container/B2/1
/container/B2/2
/container/B2/3
/container/B2/4
```

Now i want to delete all sub blobs present in B1 blob ( i.e 1,2,3,4 ). How can i delete this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically speaking, those are not "sub-blobs".  Azure blob storage has two levels, containers and blobs.  You actually have four distinct, unrelated blobs with the names "B1/1", "B1/2", "B1/3" and "B1/4", and you'd need to delete them individually.

If you just want to do it manually, utilities like [Cerebrata Cloud Storage Studio](http://www.cerebrata.com/Products/CloudStorageStudio/Default.aspx) or [Cloudberry Explorer](http://www.cloudberrylab.com/free-microsoft-azure-explorer.aspx) are invaluable tools.

Programmatically, each of the Storage Client APIs in the various SDKs has a wrapper for the [ultimate REST call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179413) that is made.  The [List Blobs API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd135734.aspx) does have an optional *delimiter* parameter to list all blobs with a given prefix, so for instance with List Blobs and a prefix of "B1/" you would get back the four blobs of interest, and then you'd issue individual deletes on them.  If you're using the .NET SDK, take a look at [this overload of ListBlobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758385) for use of the [BlobRequestOptions.UseFlatBlobListing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storageclient.blobrequestoptions_members) option)